# How to avoid image rendering over original image size in "click-enlarge mode" (css-styled-content)

Tags: typo3

If I set some value for `styles.content.imgtext.linkWrap.width` or `styles.content.imgtext.linkWrap.height` small images will be rendered to this value instead in its original size.

How can I achieve, that great images will be decreased to my value but small images won't be enlarged to this value?

Comment: maxWidth? maybe? hope it helps.

Comment: where do you mean? Typoscript or CSS? And which value should it have?

Supposing I have an Image with 400x300 Pixel an set  styles.content.imgtext.linkWrap.width = 800m which ist the default value, my Image will be rendered witch 800x600 Pixel. What can I do with maxWidth here?

Comment: styles.content.imgtext.linkWrap.maxWidth instead of styles.content.imgtext.linkWrap.width? Not 100% sure but figured it might help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the following setting in the TYPO3 Install Tool:

```
[GFX][processor_allowUpscaling]
```

Uncheck this checkbox to prevent upscaling of smaller images.